# Understanding iperf3 results

Tags: networking, iperf

want to know, does the bitrate stats in iperf3 for UDP only consider payload data sent per unit time or payload data + length of headers sent per unit time?

```
Sample Stats:
-----------------------------------------------------------
Server listening on 5201
-----------------------------------------------------------
Accepted connection from 10.0.1.1, port 39099
[  5] local 10.0.1.2 port 5201 connected to 10.0.1.1 port 50000
[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bitrate         Jitter    Lost/Total Datagrams
0.00-0.10   sec  1.44 KBytes   118 Kbits/sec  98197536003.664 ms  0/1 (0%)  
0.10-0.20   sec  7.88 MBytes   662 Mbits/sec  0.014 ms  0/5612 (0%)  
0.20-0.30   sec  11.3 MBytes   949 Mbits/sec  0.012 ms  0/8063 (0%)  
0.30-0.40   sec  11.3 MBytes   949 Mbits/sec  0.025 ms  0/8062 (0%)  
0.40-0.50   sec  11.3 MBytes   950 Mbits/sec  0.026 ms  0/8060 (0%)
```